# Solving Double Summation equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

So the problem is:

> $$\sum_{j=1}^n\, \sum_{k=3}^j k$$

Was wondering if I solved this right, or maybe you can catch some mistakes I might have made? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Mistake at the bottom of the first line $j(j+1)=j^2+j$ ...

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks! Made the adjustments and edited in a new picture of solution.

Comment: Cool ... looks fine now ... $-32n$ & cancel a factor of $2$ to complete the task.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the summation effectively runs from $j=3$ instead of $j=1$.

**Method 1**

Put $k'=k-2, j'=j-2$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=3}^jk
&=\sum_{j=3}^n\sum_{k=3}^jk\\
&=\sum_{j'=1}^{n-2}\sum_{k'=1}^{\;j'} k'+2\\
&=\sum_{j'=1}^{n-2}\binom {j'+1}2+2j'\\
&=\binom n3+2\binom {n-1}2\\
&=\frac {n+6}3\binom {n-1}2\\
&=\frac {(n+6)(n-1)(n-2)}6\\
&=\frac {n^3}6+\frac {n^2}2-\frac {8n}3+2
\end{align}$$

**Method 2**
(*This is similar to yours but with some shortcuts.*)

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=3}^jk
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^jk\right)-\big(n\cdot 1+(n-1)\cdot 2\big)\\
&=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\binom {j+1}2\right)-(3n-2)\\
&=\binom {n+2}3-(3n-2)\\
&=\frac {n^3}6+\frac {n^2}2-\frac {8n}3+2\end{align}$$

---

**Note**

Note also that 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=3}^jk=(n-2)\cdot 3+(n-3)\cdot 4+(n-4)\cdot 5+\cdots+1\cdot n$$